# Ошибка компиляции проекта (Lombok)

Tags: android, компиляция, lombok

Проект не компилируется только при попытке сгенерировать подписанный apk
gradle:

```
...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
...
```

Если коротко то пишет:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Users\Astend\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.projectlombok\lombok\1.18.2\524e0a697e9d62950b2f763d88d35cd8dc82a9a1\lombok-1.18.2.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Can't process class [module-info.class] (Unsupported class version number [53.0] (maximum 52.0, Java 1.8)))
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't process class [module-info.class] (Unsupported class version number [53.0] (maximum 52.0, Java 1.8))
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported class version number [53.0] (maximum 52.0, Java 1.8)
```

Может кто сталкивался такой проблемой и знает что сделать что бы скомпилировать проект?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170502/proguard-says-unsupported-class-version-number-52-0-maximum-51-0-java-1-7-w

Comment: Версия AS и Gradle Plugin?

Comment: AS = 3.1.4 ___ Gradle Version = 4.4

Comment: _"Unsupported class version number [53.0] (maximum 52.0, Java 1.8)"_ - кажется, надо что-то обновить.

Answer (score 0):

Запустите в терминале AS команду:

> ./gradlew buildEnvironment

И найдите версию ProGuard (пример AS 3.2.1):

```
|    +--- net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3
|    |    \--- net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:6.0.3
```

`ProGuard` начиная с версии `6.0` должен понимать `Java 9` байткод.

**Дополнено**
AS начиная с версии `3.2` включает в себя `ProGuard 6`.

Comment: После запуска с терминала вылазит такая вот ошибка: 
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)  
...  at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:782)

Answer (score -1):

Пришлось вызреть lombok из программы, вроде все заработало хорошо.

Comment: Достаточно было просто обновить студию, 3.1.4 ссылается на ProGuard без поддержки Java 9: `net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:5.3.3`. Но если lombok вам и не нужен, не понятно о чем тогда вообще вопрос?